# Infix epression evaluation

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, math-expression-eval, ocaml

I'm looking for some feedback on my OCaml implementation of some methods to translate infix expressions to postfix and then evaluate them.

I'm very new to OCaml, coming from C#/Java and JavaScript so pretty much any advice is appreciated, in particular how to make it more idiomatic or "functional".

It seems like I have to reverse my stack at some point because I want to operate on both sides, is this unavoidable? Could I be using better exceptions for my helper functions? Is it good practice to declare helper functions like I did? `apply_and_store` and `str_to_fn` could be inside `eval_postfix`, is it better to have them encapsulated or to keep `eval_postfix` cleaner?

```
let explode_to_strings (s : string) : string list =
    Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") s;;

(* Method from pleac.sourceforge.net *)
let is_Integer (s : string) : bool =
    try ignore (int_of_string s); true with Failure _ -> false;;

let str_to_fn (s : string) : (int -> int -> int) =
    match s with 
    | "+" -> (+)
    | "-" -> (-)
    | "*" -> ( * )
    | "/" -> (/)
    | _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "Not an operator");;

let apply_and_store (lst : 'a list) (fn : 'a -> 'a -> 'a) : 'a list =
    match lst with 
    | one :: two :: tl -> fn two one :: tl
    | _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "List too short");;

let prec (s : string) : int =
    match s with
    | "+" | "-" -> 1
    | "*" | "/" -> 2 
    | _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "Not in operator table");;

let infix_to_postfix (lst : string list) : string list =
    let rec 
        push (elem : string) (output : string list) (ops : string list) : (string list * string list) =
            match ops with
            | [] -> (output, elem :: ops)
            | hd :: tl ->   if prec elem <= prec hd 
                            then push elem (hd :: output) tl
                            else (output, elem :: ops)
    in
    let rec 
        aux (l : string list) (output : string list) (ops : string list) : string list =
            match l with 
            | [] -> ops @ output
            | hd :: tl ->   if is_Integer hd 
                            then aux tl (hd :: output) ops 
                            else let ret = push hd output ops in 
                                aux tl (fst ret) (snd ret)
    in
    aux lst [] [];;

let eval_postfix (lst : string list) : int =
    let rec aux (l : string list) (stack : int list) : int =
        match l with 
        | [] -> List.nth stack 0
        | hd :: tl ->   if is_Integer hd 
                        then aux tl ((int_of_string hd) :: stack)
                        else aux tl (apply_and_store stack (str_to_fn hd)) in
    aux (List.rev lst) [];;

let eval_infix (s : string) : int =
    eval_postfix (infix_to_postfix (explode_to_strings s));;
```

Comment: if you need to invert your input, doesn't it mean that you actually produced prefix expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Do not write explicit types!  Symbolic processing is easy in OCaml, use it to your advantage instead of mimicking cryptic algorithms which are only useful in languages where symbolic processing is a pain – as C, C++ or Java.

---

In OCaml, we never write explicitly write types, as they do in C++ or Java. There is usually no point to do that, since the compiler computes the types for you. If you want to see the types inferred, you can use the `-i` option of the compiler, or better, use [merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin) to see the types interactively.

When we write larger programs, we write signature files where we specify the signatures of public functions and abstract types, but this more a software engineering technique you should not bother much while you do your very first steps.

If you do not have to handle the typing information by yourself, your code is much easier to edit, take advantage of this freedom instead of binding yourself again with your old ties!

I could let your code run after a few minor modifications and found out it did not work as expected.  When I read your code, I have difficulties to understand what happens, it is probably a bit too clever – and broken.

There is an important object of the problem that does not appear in your code, it is the abstract syntactic tree (AST) associated to your expression.  If you can generate it from infix, it is trivial to generate the prefix or postfix expression out of it.  In languages like C, C++ or Java, working with ASTs is painful, but ML languages were designed to make this easy.

Here is how we define the type of arithmetic expressions:

```
  type t =
    | Integer of int
    | Binary of binary * t * t
  and binary =
    | Add
    | Sub
    | Mult
    | Div
```

It is very easy to handle, say if you want to evaluate an expression

```
  let rec eval = function
  | Integer(k) -> k
  | Binary(op, a, b) ->
     (match op with
      | Add -> ( + )
      | Sub -> ( - ) 
      | Mult -> ( * )
      | Div -> ( / )) (eval a) (eval b)
```

or implement algebraic expansion

```
  let rec expand = function
  | (Integer(_) | Binary((Add | Sub), _, _)) as a -> a
  | Binary(Mult, Binary(Add, a, b), c) -> …
```

I do not write the full function, but I hope you get the idea.

Now, the best way to solve our problem is to write a parser converting infix expression from their concrete syntax to an AST.  In practical situations, we should use ocamllex and ocamlyacc to generate the lexer and the parser for arithmetic expressions, but let us write everything manually.

The first step is lexing, which you got pretty right, but let me rewrite it this way, defining a type for tokens and using a more capable regular expression:

```
  type token =
    | INTEGER of int
    | ADD
    | SUB
    | MULT
    | DIV

  let lexer s =
    let open Str in
    split (regexp " +\\|\\b *") s
    |> List.map
      (function
        | "+" -> ADD
        | "-" -> SUB
        | "*" -> MULT
        | "/" -> DIV
        | n -> (try INTEGER(int_of_string n)
                with _ -> ksprintf failwith "lexer: Invalid token: %s" n))
```

You can see the `\b` code for *word boundary*, it allows to process correctly text with fewer spaces:

```
# lexer "1+41*2-5/ 7";;
- : token list =
[INTEGER 1; ADD; INTEGER 41; MULT; INTEGER 2; SUB; INTEGER 5; DIV; INTEGER 7]
```

Once we have converted the string to a token list, it is very easy to analyse its structure, using a *continuation-passing-style-mutually-recursive-functions* which is much easier as the pedantic designation I wrote can suggest it. :)

We first need a help function

```
  let _binop op a b =
    Binary(op, a, b)
```

Now the parser itself looks like this:

```
  let rec parser_entry cont =
    function
    | [] -> failwith "Unexpected end of input"
    | INTEGER(k) :: ADD :: tl -> cont(parser_entry (_binop Add (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: SUB :: tl -> cont(parser_entry (_binop Sub (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: MULT :: tl -> cont(parser_mult (_binop Mult (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: DIV :: tl -> cont(parser_mult (_binop Div (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: [] -> cont (Integer(k))
    | _ -> failwith "Syntax error"
  and parser_mult cont =
    function
    | [] ->  failwith "Unexpected end of input"
    | INTEGER(k) :: ADD :: tl ->
        (_binop Add (cont (Integer(k)))) (parser_entry (fun x -> x) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: SUB :: tl ->
        (_binop Sub (cont (Integer(k)))) (parser_entry (fun x -> x) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: MULT :: tl ->
        cont (parser_mult (_binop Mult (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: DIV :: tl ->
        cont (parser_mult (_binop Div (Integer(k))) tl)
    | INTEGER(k) :: [] -> cont (Integer(k))
    | _ -> failwith "Syntax error"
  and parser lst =
    parser_entry (fun x -> x) lst
```

The `parser_entry` function is the entry point for the parser and `parser_mult` reads multiplications and divisions.  The functions have two parameters `cont` the famous *continuation* and the list of tokens they need to process.  The continuation encodes the current state of the parser, it is reminiscent of the stack found in LALR parsers. As you see, when parsing in the entry point, the continuation is the outermost function called but in when parsing operators with a priority, the continuation is deeply nested, which is how the priority is represented in the program. Let's try our parser:

```
# parser(lexer("1"));;
- : t = Integer 1
# parser(lexer("1 +2 - 3"));;
- : t =
Binary (Add, Integer 1, Binary (Sub, Integer 2, Integer 3))
# parser(lexer "1+41*2-5/ 7");;
- : t =
Binary (Add, Integer 1,
 Binary (Sub, Binary (Mult, Integer 41, Integer 2),
  Binary (Div, Integer 5, Integer 7)))
```

Now it is is trivial to convert an abstract expression to prefix notation:

```
  let rec to_prefix_string = function
    | Integer(k) -> string_of_int k
    | Binary(op, a, b) ->
        String.concat " " [
          (match op with
           | Add -> "+"
           | Sub -> "-"
           | Mult -> "*"
           | Div -> "/");
          to_prefix_string a;
          to_prefix_string b
        ]
```

The advantage of symbolic processing is that the code is very explicit!  Now we write a convenience function:

```
  let infix_to_prefix s =
    to_prefix_string(parser(lexer s))
```

and try it!

```
# infix_to_prefix "1+41*2-5/ 7";;
- : string = "+ 1 - * 41 2 / 5 7"
```

Comment: Cool answer! Also interesting too see that in OCaml explicit types are discouraged while they are encouraged in Haskell

Comment: OCaml has to type of files: implementation files (for code) and signature file (for signatures).  While it is perfectly possible to write signatures in implementation files, the common practice is to do this only in signature files, where you also put the documentation. In Haskell, there is no such a distinction, so that you usually see signatures and code interleaved.

In explorative programming, we usually skip types. :)